# How to summarize number of products purchased by a customer based on a product list in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tidyr, summarize

I have two dataframes in R, one consisting of a list of product SKUs (product ids), the other of a purchase log containing the order number, the customer email, the purchase date as well as the product id  (product_sku) and quantity purchased.

**purchases_dataframe:**

```
order_number | email                | product_sku | quantity | purchase_date
1000         |customer1@sample.com  | RT-100      | 2        | 2020-01-01
1000         |customer1@sample.com  | CT-300      | 1        | 2020-01-01
1000         |customer1@sample.com  | Phone-100   | 1        | 2020-01-01
2000         |customer2@sample.com  | Phone-200   | 1        | 2020-04-20
2000         |customer2@sample.com  | OM-200      | 1        | 2020-04-20
3000         |customer3@sample.com  | CT-300      | 3        | 2020-03-15
4000         |customer1@sample.com  | OM-200      | 5        | 2020-07-07
5000         |customer4@sample.com  | Phone-200   | 3        | 2020-08-19
6000         |customer3@sample.com  | Phone-100   | 1        | 2020-09-22
6000         |customer3@sample.com  | RT-100      | 1        | 2020-09-22
```

**tv_list:**

```
 SKU
    RT-100
    CT-300
    OM-200
    LL-400
    ...
```

I would like to count the total number of TVs a customer has purchased in his/her lifetime and disregard all other products (e.g. phones). The dataframe **tv_list** should help me identify which SKUs are TVs and which are not, as I have a variety of different TV SKUs and the above is just a smaller example.
The resulting dataframe would ideally look like this:

```
email                | number_purchased_tv
customer1@sample.com | 8
customer2@sample.com | 1
customer3@sample.com | 4
customer4@sample.com | 0
```

For reproducability and in order to easier follow my examples, here is **the code for the two sample_tables above**:

```
purchase_dataframe <- data.frame(order_number = c(1000,1000,1000, 2000,2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 6000),
                      email = c("customer1@sample.com","customer1@sample.com", "customer1@sample.com","customer2@sample.com",
                                "customer2@sample.com","customer3@sample.com","customer1@sample.com","customer4@sample.com",
                                "customer3@sample.com","customer3@sample.com"),
                      product_sku = c("RT-100", "CT-300", "Phone-100", "Phone-200", "OM-200", "CT-300", "OM-200", "Phone-200", "Phone-100", "RT-100"),
                      quantity = c(2,1,1,1,1,3,5,3,1,1),
                      purchase_date = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-04-20","2020-04-20","2020-03-15","2020-07-07","2020-08-19","2020-09-22","2020-09-22"))

tv_list <- data.frame(SKU = c("RT-100", "OM-200", "CT-300", "LL-400", "ZV-700"))
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below does what you requested using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
purchase_dataframe %>% dplyr::group_by(email) %>% dplyr::summarise(sumtv = sum(quantity[product_sku %in% unique(tv_list$SKU)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
email                sumtv
<chr>                <dbl>
  1 customer1@sample.com     8
2 customer2@sample.com     1
3 customer3@sample.com     4
4 customer4@sample.com     0
```

---

**EDIT** please find a correction above regarding the `sumtv` figure and a `data.table` solution below

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
purchase_datatable <- purchase_dataframe
purchase_datatable %>% setDT
> purchase_datatable[,sumtv := sum(quantity[product_sku %in% unique(tv_list$SKU)]), by="email"][
  +   ,.(email, sumtv)] %>% unique
email sumtv
1: customer1@sample.com     8
2: customer2@sample.com     1
3: customer3@sample.com     4
4: customer4@sample.com     0
```

---

`microbenchmark`ing gives almost a 50% advantage to the `data.table` solution which IMO is an excellent package well worth learning through these [vignettes](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/doc/index.html)

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(purchase_datatable[,sumtv := sum(quantity[product_sku %in% unique(tv_list$SKU)]), by="email"][
  ,.(email, sumtv)] %>% unique, purchase_dataframe %>% dplyr::group_by(email) %>% dplyr::summarise(sumtv = sum(quantity[product_sku %in% unique(tv_list$SKU)]))
)
min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
1.268 1.42700 1.823445 1.80300 2.0887 2.8332   100
2.715 2.98025 3.250287 3.20355 3.3509 8.8255   100
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick answer! Unfortunately, this does not result in the correct quanity sum - it seems that only orders are summarized. For customer 1, the sum should be 8 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! For some reason, the data.table solution gives me the following warning: In `[.data.table`(purchase_datatable, product_sku %in% unique(tv_list$SKU),  :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters due to the "Warning message". For some reason, it also does not return the "unique" table - but maybe this is related to the warning message above.

Comment: did you load both `dplyr` and `data.table`? if not you should do so, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Just checked again. I think the dplyr solution worked, if I am not mistaken. Thanks! However, the data.table solution does not aggregate customers (as you can see in your output, customer1 and customer 3 are in there two times, with 2 different values)

Comment: you are right, this is corrected now in both parts of my answer related to `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

One option using `base R`:

```
#Match and index
purchase_dataframe$ProductIndex <- tv_list[match(purchase_dataframe$product_sku,tv_list$SKU),'SKU']
purchase_dataframe$Counter <- ifelse(is.na(purchase_dataframe$ProductIndex),0,purchase_dataframe$quantity)
#Aggregate
Res <- aggregate(Counter~email,data=purchase_dataframe,sum,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
                 email Counter
1 customer1@sample.com       8
2 customer2@sample.com       1
3 customer3@sample.com       4
4 customer4@sample.com       0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the data you provided:

```
library('dplyr')
purchase_dataframe <- data.frame(order_number = c(1000,1000,1000, 2000,2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 6000),
                      email = c("customer1@sample.com","customer1@sample.com", "customer1@sample.com","customer2@sample.com",
                                "customer2@sample.com","customer3@sample.com","customer1@sample.com","customer4@sample.com",
                                "customer3@sample.com","customer3@sample.com"),
                      product_sku = c("RT-100", "CT-300", "Phone-100", "Phone-200", "OM-200", "CT-300", "OM-200", "Phone-200", "Phone-100", "RT-100"),
                      quantity = c(2,1,1,1,1,3,5,3,1,1),
                      purchase_date = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-04-20","2020-04-20","2020-03-15","2020-07-07","2020-08-19","2020-09-22","2020-09-22"))

tv_list <- data.frame(SKU = c("RT-100", "OM-200", "CT-300", "LL-400", "ZV-700"))
```

This will give you the summary but omit any email(customer that haven't purchase a tv yet)

```
total_tvs_by_cusomter <- purchase_dataframe %>%
  filter(product_sku %in% tv_list$SKU) %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  mutate(quantity = as.numeric(quantity)) %>%
  summarise(number_purchased_tv = sum(quantity))
```

Outcome:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  email                number_purchased_tv
  <chr>                              <dbl>
1 customer1@sample.com                   8
2 customer2@sample.com                   1
3 customer3@sample.com                   4
```

and this is in case if you want to keep the emails/customers that haven't yet bought a TV and add them as 0

```
total_tvs_by_cusomter <- left_join(unique(purchase_dataframe %>%
            select(email)), total_tvs_by_cusomter)

total_tvs_by_cusomter[is.na(total_tvs_by_cusomter)] <- 0
```

Outcome:

```
                 email number_purchased_tv
1 customer1@sample.com                   8
2 customer2@sample.com                   1
3 customer3@sample.com                   4
4 customer4@sample.com                   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tv_purchases <-
purchase_dataframe %>% 
  group_by(email) %>% 
  filter(product_sku %in% tv_list$SKU) %>%
  summarise(number_purchased_tv = sum(as.numeric(quantity)))

## join tv_purchases on distinct emails, to also have the 'customer4@sample.com     0' row

purchase_dataframe %>%
  distinct(email) %>%
  left_join(tv_purchases) %>% ## emails which are not in tv_purchases will have NAs
  mutate(number_purchased_tv = case_when(is.na(number_purchased_tv) ~ 0, ## NAs become zeros
                                         TRUE ~ number_purchased_tv) ## non-NAs stay as they are
         )
```